# Не добавляются элементы в custom listview

Tags: android

Ребята помогите. Проблема. Работаю с Firebase.
Создал кастомный ListView все работает. Но когда я беру данные с Firebase элементерно не добавляются items хоть и все верно.

Проблема в том что внутри while не срабатывают вот эти строки

```
MessagesClass chatListClass = new MessagesClass();
            chatListClass.setName(cName);

            messagesClassArrayList.add(chatListClass);
```

Снаруж while все работает корректно.
Код:

```
messagesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainChatLW);

    messagesClassArrayList = new ArrayList<MessagesClass>();
    adapter = new MessagesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.messages_lw_items, messagesClassArrayList);
    messagesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/rooms/888P0RVL/chat/");

    root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            messagesClassArrayList.clear();


            while (i.hasNext()) {
                DataSnapshot dS = ((DataSnapshot) i.next());
                String cName = dS.child("name").getValue().toString();

                MessagesClass chatListClass = new MessagesClass();
                chatListClass.setName(cName);

                messagesClassArrayList.add(chatListClass);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: посмотри дебаггером что у тебя в messagesClassArrayList. Данные есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось простым, что странно работало раньше без этого.

Оказывается после метода while надо было вызвать функцию

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```